# requireJS “Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function”

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I have been using requirejs on couple projects, and today is the first time I got this problem and not sure how to fix it. I am using requirejs and tyepscript, I can't really tell what's wrong here. Can someone take a look?

Here is my main.ts:

```
///<reference path="../lib/require/requirejs.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="TestClass.ts"/>
require.config(
    {
        baseUrl: 'js',
        paths: {
            puremvc: 'lib/puremvc/puremvc_standard_1.0_min'
        }
    }
);
require(
    [
        'puremvc',
        'sim/TestClass'
    ],
    function (TestClass ) {
        var test = new TestClass();
        test.logMsg("WHO AM I");
    }
);
```

and this is my TestClass.ts

```
class TestClass{
    constructor(){
        console.log ("TestClass constructor")
    }
   public logMsg(msg:string){
        console.log ("TestClass.log(): " + msg);
    }
}
export = TestClass;
```

and my sim.html looks like this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Simulation Tester</title>
<script src="js/lib/puremvc/puremvc_standard_1.0_min.js"></script>
<script data-main="js/sim/main.js" src="js/lib/require/require.js" ></script>
</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my folder structure:

```
- root 
    - sim.html
    - js
        - lib
            - require (containt requirejs)
        - sim
            - main.ts
            - TestClass.ts
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading puremvc through the script tag, or through require.js? I don't think you want to do both.

Over here:

```
require(
    [
        'puremvc',
        'sim/TestClass'
    ],
    function (TestClass ) {
        var test = new TestClass();
        test.logMsg("WHO AM I");
    }
);
```

The callback function gets the modules *in the same order you listed them*. So the 'TestClass' parameter is being supplied the value from the 'puremvc' module. You probably want `function(puremvc, TestClass)` instead here.

Comment: That's it. I remove puremvc script tag from HTML and change the function(TestClass) to function (puremvc, TestClass) Thank you so much. I guess I've been doing it all wrong a while but now today is the first time I got this error. Thanks again.